# Where Laravel Storage save the files?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

hope you are doing really good today, I'm trying to copy a file using the function copy from Laravel Storage, but I don't know where it is saving them cause the first time looks normal but after the second shot I got an error about the file already exists, but I don't know where is saving it, this is my code, $dirDest should be a folder inside of my project but is not saving it there and I've already searched it in the ftp directory, hope you can help me.

````
$dirDest = 'temp-docs\temp.pdf';
Storage::disk('custom-ftp')->copy($this->document_path, $dirDest);```

Regards!
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the path you have configured for your 'custom-ftp' in *filesystems.php*. This part:

```
'custom-ftp' => [
    ...
    'root' => 'your/base/path',
    ...
],
```

You file copy will be located in this **root folder + 'temp-docs\temp.pdf'**

The copy function does not changes the driver. So it copies just inside of your ftp server.

---

To copy the file from one server to another (or your server) use a combination of **get** and **put** functions from the storage drivers.

```
$file = Storage::disk('my_ftp')->get($this->document_path);
Storage::disk('other_ftp')->put('temp-docs\temp.pdf', $file);
```

After that you will find the file of the other server **root folder + 'temp-docs\temp.pdf'**

I would also recommend you use the **exists** function to be sure that the file is there before you copy it.

```
Storage::disk('my_ftp')->exists($this->document_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to close and reopen the folder cause it was not refreshing hehe, by any chance do you know how copy the file outside of the custon-ftp path? I need it in another server.

Comment: @CesarVillaseñor I have extended my answer with an example how to achieve this. Using the same approach in one of my projects.

Comment: @Sergei Tihonov, thanks a lot, I really appreciate it and it's so helpfull